# How to use init method using x, y, width, height in Opencv3 Tracker?

Tags: python, opencv

Other examples I've seen use selectROI to declare boundingBox, but I know information about x, y, width, height, and I want to use it to declare boundingBox. However, if the boundingBox is not a data type of cv2.typing.Rect an error occurs.

My code:

```
tracker = cv.Tracker('CSRT')

# ex) initial_bbox = (0, 0, 100, 100)
initial_bbox = (x, y, width, height)
tracker.init(frame, initial_bbox)
```

Error:

> Can't parse 'boundingBox'. Sequence item with index 0 has a wrong type

Comment: Cast your parameters to integers before passing them to the init method: `(int(x), int(y), int(width), int(height))`